# when I use a pandas.core.series.Series the float' object has no 'nlargest' attribute while with pandas.core.frame.DataFrame it has one

Tags: python, pandas, attributes, apply

Goal is to find the top 5 of the english films from Netflix 's data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

From kaggle

```
url1 = 'netflix_titles.csv';df1 = pd.read_csv(url1)
url2 = 'titles_ntfix.csv';df2 = pd.read_csv(url2)
All_content = df1.merge(right=df2, on=["title","release_year"], how='inner')
All_content[(All_content["country"] == 'United Kingdom') & (All_content["type"] == 'Movie')]['imdb_votes'].apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(5))
```

code produces:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'nlargest'

Why does that fail? While if I code:

```
English_film = All_content[(All_content["country"] == 'United Kingdom') & (All_content["type"] == 'Movie')]['imdb_votes']
English_film = pd.DataFrame(English_film)
English_film.apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(5))
```

Why does that work?

```
    imdb_votes
2233    530877.0
1023    160806.0
680     71915.0
927     40447.0
904     38870.0
```

Do you have any better way?
Regards,
Atapalou

Answer (score 1):

In following code, you are calling `Series.apply`, `x` in `lambda x` is value in Series.

```py
All_content[(All_content["country"] == 'United Kingdom') & (All_content["type"] == 'Movie')]['imdb_votes'].apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(5))
```

In following code, you are calling `DataFrame.apply`. `x` in `lambda x` is a column in DataFrame which is Series type.

```py
English_film.apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(5))
```